# How to Remove a Sound

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

Hey guys so I can't figure this out. I want to Remove a single sound from a Class. So I have a start screen and when you press "Play Game" it takes you to the game but the start screen music keeps playing. Ive tried sound mixer remove all sounds which works but it removes every sound in the game even the Main game music. So i just to remove this single sound which is added in its class like so:

```
public class mcStartGameScreen extends MovieClip 
{
    private var sndmainSong:Sound;
    public var mcStart:MovieClip;

    public function mcStartGameScreen() 
    {
        mcStart.buttonMode = true;
        mcStart.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, startOnTouch, false, 0, true)
        //To completely end game when back button pushed on android
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown, false, 0, true);



        //create sound object from main song in library
        sndmainSong = new DST10Class();
        sndmainSong.play();
    }
```

Now i want to remove the sound through the mcStart event listener function which is this:

```
private function startOnTouch(e:TouchEvent):void 
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event("START_GAME"));


             //Tried null but didnt work either
           //DST10Class = null;

    }
```

So is their any easy way i can acccomplish this? Any help will be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Get a handler of the playing sound, then call `stop()` when you need to stop it.

```
var mainChannel:SoundChannel;
sndmainSong = new DST10Class();
mainChannel=sndmainSong.play();
```

Then, to stop it you call `mainChannel.stop()` and your sound will stop. To play it again, you need to create another `SoundChannel` object via `sndmainSong.play()`.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!I love you Vesper so much man. You are a AS3 Genius. Seriously you have helped me so mch through my game. Im going to release it on the Android market place soon. I would love to gie you credit. Do you have a website or anything that i can link my game to if you want that is

Comment: @user2233653 I don't have a personal website, although I'd like you to link a TD.net community at http://towerdefen.se which currently hosts my project in progress and supports me with help and encouragement.

Comment: SOunds great Vesper ill inform you when i complete the game. Sometime between august and september.

Comment: Taking longer than expected. But the game I've been working will be finished soon. Ran into a lot of bugs which i can't figure out yet.

Comment: Perhaps nail them one by one? Open a new question for one of the worst ones, and see if SO will help you nail it.